# F# I want to filter my output

Tags: f#

I have a problem which I have simplified for the purpose of this question.
Let's just say I have 2 lists. The first *actually represents a list of classes but* for this purpose, let's say it simply represents a list of ints (2,4,6,8,10). I have another list of ints that represents flags, indicating if I wish to include/exclude the corresponding values from the first set.
  *(It's not the best example but should suffice for helping me solve my real problem.)*

```
let set1 = [2;4;6;8;10]
let set2 = [1;0;0;1;1]
```

My **desired output** set is:

```
[2;8;10]
```

This is my code:

```
let solution = 
    List.map2 (fun a b -> 
        match b with
        | 1 -> a 
        | _ -> 0
    ) set1 set2
```

this renders the following output:

```
val solution : int list = [2; 0; 0; 8; 10]
```

How can I filter out these undesired zeros? 
Instead of `| _ -> 0` I ideally want to return a null and then filter out all nulls.

Your help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one seems to be reasonable easy:

```
let filterWith set2 set1 =
    List.zip set1 set2 
    |> List.filter (fun (_,x) -> x=1) 
    |> List.map fst
```

usage:

```
let set1 = [2;4;6;8;10]
let set2 = [1;0;0;1;1]

set1 |> filterWith set1
```

---

if you would choose to use a list of `bool`s for your `set2` it could get a bit nicer:

```
let filterWith set2 set1 =
    List.zip set1 set2 
    |> List.filter snd
    |> List.map fst
```

usage:

```
let set1 = [2;4;6;8;10]
let set2 = [true;false;false;true;true]

set1 |> filterWith set1
```

Comment: The last two can be replaced with `List.choose (fun (x, key) -> if key then Some x else None)`

Comment: …or even `List.choose (function (x, true) -> Some x | _ -> None)`

Answer (score 3):

```
List.zip set1 set2
|> List.filter (snd >> (<>) 0)
|> List.map fst
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version using fold and a predicate function to keep the flags generic. I had some fun with the flags :)

```
let filterByFlag pred l flags =
  List.zip l flags
  |> List.fold (fun s (x,flag) -> if pred(flag) then x::s else s) []
  |> List.rev

let l = [2;4;6;8;10]
let flags = ["";"";"";"";""]

filterByFlag (fun t -> t = "") l flags
>val it : int list = [2; 8; 10]
```

Comment: Very handy. Thanks for your input and interesting flags you've got going there :-)

Comment: @Kevin, Instead fold + rev you can use foldBack :)

Answer (score 1):

I will add 3 variants: :)

```
let set1 = [2;4;6;8;10]
let set2 = [1;0;0;1;1]

let filterWith2 (set1:int list) (set2:int list) = 
    [0..set1.Length-1]
    |> List.choose (fun i ->
        match set2.[i] with
        | 1 -> Some set1.[i]
        | _ -> None)

let filterWith3 (set1:int list) (set2:int list) = 
      List.foldBack2(fun x y acc -> if y=1 then x::acc else acc) set1 set2 [] 

open System.Linq
let filterWith4 (set1:int list) (set2:int list) = 
      set1.Where(fun _ i -> set2.[i]=1) |> List.ofSeq

filterWith2 set1 set2 |> printfn "%A"
filterWith3 set1 set2 |> printfn "%A"
filterWith4 set1 set2 |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
[2; 8; 10]
[2; 8; 10]
[2; 8; 10]
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/UaHuTk

Comment: Thanks - very instructive ... so many different ways to do the same thing in F# ... love it!

Comment: I'm still missing the List Expression, which would be shortest: `[ for x,y in List.zip set1 set2 do if y <> 0 then yield x ]`